# Django adding multiple m2m related model records using .set works fine, but how to also add additional model fields other than ids?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have `photos` model and `tags` model with m2m relationship through `phototags` model.

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, through = 'PhotoTag', related_name="tags")
```

In a view I create a list of tag ids that I use in `photo.tags.set(form_tags_ids)` to create the new `phototag` relationships. This works fine and successfully populates both `photo_id` and `tag_id` fields in `phototags` model.

However, I also have other additional fields in `phototags` model, other than the related models' ids, that I want to populate at same time eg `created date`, `user_id` to record who made relationship and when it was created.

What would be best way to populate these other columns?

The only thing I can think of is to not use `.set` and loop through the list of tag ids and manually create the `phototag` records but then I lose benefit of m2m in avoiding duplicate assignment of tag to photo, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found `through_defaults` in Django documentation which are added in `.set()` which lets me default my `user_id` and `team_id` for all tags assigned to the photo which is exactly what I was looking for.

Looks like this for my use case:

```
photo.tags.set(form_tags_ids, through_defaults={'user_id': request.user.id, 'team_id': team.id})
```

However this appears to be new to Django 2.2

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `bulk_create` method. You can add all the other params on each object creation, like this:

```
PhotoTag.objects.bulk_create([
    PhotoTag(photo=photo_id1, tag=tag1, created_date=datetime.now(), user_id=75),
    PhotoTag(photo=photo_id2, tag=tag2, created_date=datetime.now(), user_id=75),
    PhotoTag(photo=photo_id3, tag=tag3, created_date=datetime.now(), user_id=75),
])
```

Also, you can add the `unique_together` on the model relation to avoid duplicate assignments.

```
class PhotoTag(models.Model):
    photo = ...
    tag = ...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['photo', 'tag']
```

Comment: Thanks but this seems to require quite a bit of extra work to do what m2m does. I created list of tuples by mapping `form_tags_ids` ids. `bulk_create` successfully adds this list to db. While `unique_together` can be used to manage duplicates, it creates indices on db which need `try/except` to silence db messages when tries to add duplicates. And still need something else to delete tags which m2m manages. Still interested in other solutions!